# Rust OpenTelemetry OTLP w/ Honeycomb

Tags: rust, open-telemetry, otlp-grpc

I'm trying to use `opentelemetry` and `open telemetry-otlp` to provide observability data over OTLP to Honeycomb.

I'm using something like this as a proof of concept (extracted out into this repo if you want to run it: https://github.com/timfpark/honeycomb-rust-poc)

```
fn init_tracer(metadata: &MetadataMap) -> Result<sdktrace::Tracer, TraceError> {
    let opentelemetry_endpoint =
        env::var("OTEL_ENDPOINT").unwrap_or_else(|_| "https://api.honeycomb.io".to_owned());
    let opentelemetry_endpoint =
        Url::parse(&opentelemetry_endpoint).expect("OTEL_ENDPOINT is not a valid url");

    opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
        .tracing()
        .with_exporter(
            opentelemetry_otlp::new_exporter()
                .tonic()
                .with_endpoint(opentelemetry_endpoint.as_str())
                .with_metadata(metadata.clone())
                .with_tls_config(
                    ClientTlsConfig::new().domain_name(
                        opentelemetry_endpoint
                            .host_str()
                            .expect("OTEL_ENDPOINTshould have a valid host"),
                    ),
                ),
        )
        .install_batch(opentelemetry::runtime::Tokio)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {

    let mut metadata = MetadataMap::with_capacity(2);

    metadata.insert(
        "x-honeycomb-team",
        "...honeycomb api key...".parse().unwrap(),
    );

    metadata.insert("x-honeycomb-dataset", "my-api".parse().unwrap());

    let tracer = init_tracer(&metadata).expect("failed to instantiate opentelemetry tracing");

    tracing_subscriber::registry()
        .with(tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter::from_default_env())
        .with(tracing_opentelemetry::layer().with_tracer(tracer))
        .with(tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer())
        .try_init()
        .expect("failed to register tracer with registry");

    let tracer = global::tracer("ex.com/basic");
```

but I am getting:

```
2022-11-02T17:01:01.088429Z DEBUG hyper::client::connect::http: connecting to 52.5.162.226:443
2022-11-02T17:01:01.170767Z DEBUG hyper::client::connect::http: connected to 52.5.162.226:443
2022-11-02T17:01:01.171870Z DEBUG rustls::client::hs: No cached session for DnsName(DnsName(DnsName("api.honeycomb.io")))
2022-11-02T17:01:01.172555Z DEBUG rustls::client::hs: Not resuming any session
2022-11-02T17:01:01.269218Z DEBUG rustls::client::hs: ALPN protocol is Some(b"h2")
2022-11-02T17:01:01.269398Z DEBUG rustls::client::hs: Using ciphersuite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
2022-11-02T17:01:01.269504Z DEBUG rustls::client::tls12::server_hello: Server supports tickets
2022-11-02T17:01:01.269766Z DEBUG rustls::client::tls12: ECDHE curve is ECParameters { curve_type: NamedCurve, named_group: secp256r1 }
2022-11-02T17:01:01.269843Z DEBUG rustls::client::tls12: Server DNS name is DnsName(DnsName(DnsName("api.honeycomb.io")))
2022-11-02T17:01:01.271123Z  WARN rustls::conn: Sending fatal alert BadCertificate
2022-11-02T17:01:01.271861Z DEBUG tonic::transport::service::reconnect: reconnect::poll_ready: hyper::Error(Connect, Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: InvalidCertificateData("invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer") })
2022-11-02T17:01:01.271967Z DEBUG tower::buffer::worker: service.ready=true processing request
2022-11-02T17:01:01.272169Z DEBUG tonic::transport::service::reconnect: error: error trying to connect: invalid peer certificate contents: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer
OpenTelemetry trace error occurred. Exporter otlp encountered the following error(s): the grpc server returns error (The service is currently unavailable): , detailed error message: error trying to connect: invalid peer certificate contents: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer
```

which seems to indicate that something about my TLS setup is not correct... Does anyone have a snippet of `opentelemetry` code in Rust that works with Honeycomb?

Comment: Not a Rust expert, but you can follow the official OTel demo which shows a working configuration that's vendor netrual. From there you can just set honeycomb endpoint/api key as OTLP environment variables or in a collector: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-demo/blob/main/src/shippingservice/src/main.rs

Comment: It looks like it's become easier.  With recent versions of tonic, you can enable the feature tls-roots and it should get stuff from your system tls trust store:
`tonic = { version = "0.8.2", features = ["tls-roots"] }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, a complete solution to Rust/Honeycomb/Tracing/OpenTelemetry implementation is now available here: https://github.com/Dhghomon/rust_opentelemetry_honeycomb.

It does not need to use certs.

**UPDATE**: Expanding a little since this is the accepted answer now.

The core tracer initialization code is as follows:

```rust
fn init_tracer() -> Result<sdktrace::Tracer, TraceError> {
    opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
        .tracing()
        .with_exporter(
            opentelemetry_otlp::new_exporter()
                .http()
                .with_endpoint("https://api.honeycomb.io/v1/traces")
                .with_http_client(reqwest::Client::default())
                .with_headers(HashMap::from([
                    ("x-honeycomb-dataset".into(), DATASET_NAME.into()),
                    ("x-honeycomb-team".into(), API_KEY.into()),
                ]))
                .with_timeout(std::time::Duration::from_secs(2)),
        ) // Replace with runtime::Tokio if using async main
        .install_batch(opentelemetry::runtime::TokioCurrentThread)
}
```

The subscriber is configured like this:

```rust
let tracer = init_tracer().unwrap();
let telemetry = tracing_opentelemetry::layer().with_tracer(tracer);
let subscriber = tracing_subscriber::Registry::default().with(telemetry);
tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is: you need to give ClientTlsConfig a root certificate, that the target site (api.honeycomb.io) chains back to.

I found a suitable root cert installed in my container, and then made the program load it in.

Here's the code:

```
let pem = tokio::fs::read("/etc/ssl/certs/Starfield_Services_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem").await.expect("read the cert file");
let cert = Certificate::from_pem(pem);

let mut metadata = MetadataMap::with_capacity(1);
metadata.insert("x-honeycomb-team", honeycomb_api_key.parse().unwrap());

let opentelemetry_endpoint =
        env::var("OTEL_ENDPOINT").unwrap_or_else(|_| "https://api.honeycomb.io".to_owned());

let opentelemetry_endpoint =
        Url::parse(&opentelemetry_endpoint).expect("OTEL_ENDPOINT is not a valid url");

opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
    .tracing()
    .with_exporter(
        opentelemetry_otlp::new_exporter()
            .tonic()
            .with_endpoint(opentelemetry_endpoint.as_str())
            .with_metadata(metadata.clone())
            .with_tls_config(
                ClientTlsConfig::new().ca_certificate(cert)
            ),
    )
    .install_batch(opentelemetry::runtime::Tokio)
}
```

The first two lines are new; they load a root certificate from the filesystem.
Then use that to configure the ClientTlsConfig.

I chose that root certificate file based on the output of the certificate details:
`openssl s_client -connect api.honeycomb.io:443 -servername localhost`

The last entry in the certificate chain resembled the filename. It included: `/CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2`

Comment: This gives me the following error: "OpenTelemetry trace error occurred. cannot send span to the batch span processor because the channel is closed".

Comment: Turns out I was putting tracing initialization code in sync when my code as in async part. Put them both in async section and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @jessitron's answer I was also able to get Honeycomb working with a Rust service using a separate OpenTelemetry collector service.  The instructions for [how to configure that collector within a Kubernetes cluster are here, also by @jessitron](https://jessitron.com/2022/08/22/run-the-opentelemetry-collector-in-kubernetes-for-front-end-tracing/).

With that, then you can use a simpler configuration for reporting traces to the collector, Ala:

```
use opentelemetry::sdk::trace as sdktrace;
use opentelemetry::trace::{TraceContextExt, TraceError, Tracer};
use opentelemetry::{global, Key};
use opentelemetry_otlp::WithExportConfig;
use std::env;
use tonic::metadata::MetadataMap;
use tonic::transport::ClientTlsConfig;
use tracing_subscriber::prelude::*;
use url::Url;

fn init_tracer() -> Result<sdktrace::Tracer, TraceError> {
    // Configure OTEL_ENDPOINT to point at your collector
    let opentelemetry_endpoint =
        env::var("OTEL_ENDPOINT").unwrap_or_else(|_| "http://localhost:4317".to_owned());
    let opentelemetry_endpoint =
        Url::parse(&opentelemetry_endpoint).expect("OTEL_ENDPOINT is not a valid url");

    opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
        .tracing()
        .with_exporter(
            opentelemetry_otlp::new_exporter()
                .tonic()
                .with_endpoint(opentelemetry_endpoint.as_str()),
        )
        .install_batch(opentelemetry::runtime::Tokio)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let tracer = init_tracer().expect("failed to instantiate opentelemetry tracing");

    tracing_subscriber::registry()
        .with(tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter::from_default_env())
        .with(tracing_opentelemetry::layer().with_tracer(tracer))
        .with(tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer())
        .try_init()
        .expect("failed to register tracer with registry");

    const LEMONS_KEY: Key = Key::from_static_str("lemons");
    const ANOTHER_KEY: Key = Key::from_static_str("ex.com/another");

    let tracer = global::tracer("ex.com/basic");

    tracer.in_span("operation", |cx| {
        let span = cx.span();
        span.add_event(
            "Nice operation!".to_string(),
            vec![Key::new("bogons").i64(100)],
        );
        span.set_attribute(ANOTHER_KEY.string("yes"));

        tracer.in_span("Sub operation...", |cx| {
            let span = cx.span();
            span.set_attribute(LEMONS_KEY.string("five"));

            span.add_event("Sub span event", vec![]);
        });
    });

    loop {
        tracing::info!("just sleeping, press ctrl-c to exit");
        tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    }
}
```

As one final help, if you use the Helm chart to deploy the collector, you will want to use a configuration that looks something like this:

```
  values:
    mode: deployment
    config: 
      exporters:
        otlp/honeycomb:
          endpoint: api.honeycomb.io:443
          headers:
            "x-honeycomb-team": "{{{honeycomb-api-key}}}"
      service:
        pipelines:
          traces:
            receivers: 
              - otlp
            exporters: 
              - otlp/honeycomb
```

Thanks again to @jessitron for her clutch help. :)

Answer (score 0):

@jmagin's comment should be the accepted answer at this point.

There's no need to manually configure certs as installing tonic with `tls-roots` will provide the right CA chain.

Note that the host has to have valid certs available, so for instance if running in a Docker container, make sure they're available (e.g., `apt-get install ca-certificates` or similar)